# stylesheet(default style declarations) syntax in actionscript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, styles, stylesheet

problem is about syntax of dot formation. I wanted to assign my custom ItemRenderer in default list style but not successful yet.

> .myList
> {
> itemRenderer: com.examples.components.StyleClassRenderer;
> }

and other few try with ("com.exam...", 'com.exam...') formats didn't worked for me.
in actionscript help web page http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/StyleSheet.html,
 couldn't find any proper solution. I'll be very appreciate for your solution suggestions.

 Edit: dynamically assign by following solution 
 list.itemRenderer 
            = new ClassFactory(com.examples.components.StyleClassRenderer);
 But I want to learn how to do in Style declaration.

Comment: Can you post a bit more code?

Comment: I don't think that issue require more code to understand.I just defined a style for list, assigned colors and some other properties but in itemRenderer, got the issue.